# How to install CMake on Cygwin?

Tags: windows, cmake, cygwin, clion

I have some difficulties to use Cygwin. I need that compiler to use CLion IDE by Netbrains.
Can you explain me how to install CMake by the cygwin-terminal ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually [cmake](/questions/tagged/cmake) is not a compiler. It is a wrapper to generate files for different [make](/questions/tagged/make) like programmes. The package is available in [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin), You do not need to build from source. Before adding new package recommended to close all [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin) programmes. Then you should download the latest `setup.exe` programme ([64 bit](http://cygwin.com/setup-x86_64.exe) or or [32 bit](http://cygwin.com/setup-x86.exe) version. Launch if from Windows' cmd prompt. In the "Select Packages" dialogue you can enter `cmake` to the  "Search" edit box. If You open open the "Devel" line. Here you can check: "cmake: Cross-platform makefile generation system". Press "Next>" and Install (I think) and here you get the package...

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help but Cygwin is already installed. Have I to install a new time Cygwin and select packages ? Or can i use the terminal to install CMAKE ?

Comment: @Romain-p: You can install new packages from the setup.exe, you do not need to reinstall! Start setup.exe, press some `Next>` buttons and then You got to the "Select Packages" dialogue. Find cmake and press `Next>` again to add the new package. (Actually there is a way to install from command line, but far not trivial. So I suggest to use the GUI interface.)

Comment: But now i have to install in CMake differents under "programms":  - make, C Compiler. How to do that ?

Comment: @Romain-p: You also need make and gcc? You can also choose them in setup.exe's "Select Packages" dialogue.

Comment: ah okay but i have already choosen GCC-CORE for C compiler.. Is it the bad compiler ?

Comment: @Romain-p: No, gcc is ok!

Answer (score 2):

- Download from: http://www.cmake.org/download/
- unpack into some directory

> ```
> ./bootstrap
>   make      
>   make install
> ```

Comment: Compiling from source may not be the easier solution, but I is a good and reliable alternative. On windows, cmake installer do not provide ccmake.

Comment: And if you use git: ````git clone https://github.com/Kitware/CMake.git````