# cmake include directories issue with cygwin

Tags: cmake, cygwin

I want to add include directories to my project, which are defined in some environment variable SOME_DIR. SOME_DIR is set to 'D:\some_dir'.
Here's how I've added it in CMakeLists.txt:

```
include_directories($ENV{SOME_DIR}/include)
```

After generating Unix Makefiles via cygwin, compiler can't find header files from this directory. So, I've added some debug outputs to check list of included directories like this:

```
get_property(dirs DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} PROPERTY INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
foreach(dir ${dirs})
  message(STATUS "dir='${dir}'")
endforeach()
```

Output is:

```
dir='/cygdrive/d/myproject/D:/some_dir/include'
```

My question is: What should I do so that cmake include correct path, i.e. 'D:/some_dir/include'?

Comment: Do you run the [Cygwin CMake version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172562/how-to-install-cmake-on-cygwin)? The paths look like coming from a Windows version of CMake.

Comment: I think it is cygwin cmake. I've installed it through cygwin, and removed Windows version of cmake from PATH variable.

Comment: cygwin seems to set some strange path here. If you are inside a cygwin shell you may have do adjust the path to the cygwin format. In "unix" format you don't have `D:/..` so maybe you shoudl set `SOMEDIR` to `/cygdrive/d/some_dir`

Comment: OK, but in this case I can't use this variable for VS builds, right?