# Jetbrains CLion Toolchains: "CMake: test run timed out"

Tags: c++, cmake, ide, clion

I've just installed Jetbrains CLion onto a Windows 10 machine and I can't seem to get the toolchains set up correctly. I've installed all the required packages using Cgywin (packages located at C:\cygwin64\bin) but CLion can't seem to find these and gives the error "CMake: test run timed out". Please see the screenshot showing the error below. Anyone got any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Did you try to use custom Cygwin CMake and/or standalone one? Also check your installed packages, there should be: cmake, gnu make, gnu gcc-core, gnu gcc-g++, libgcc1. Anyway I would suggest to use [MinGW-w64](https://mingw-w64.org/doku.php) under windows, unless your project include something UNIX specific.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you need to install `CMake` for `cygwin`. `CMake` is not in set of default packages.  Please, read
[How to install CMake on Cygwin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28172562/how-to-install-cmake-on-cygwin)

Comment: CMake is definitely installed, and I've already tried reinstalling it. Initially it shows a tick next to CMake, while it appears to be searching for make, C compiler and C++ compiler before timing out and showing the above dialog.

Comment: `CMake` from `https://cmake.org/download/` will not work with `cygwin`. Please, be sure that you install the `CMake` from `cygwin` package manager.

Comment: This was installed via cygwin as noted in the original question